# How to create an unevaluated command like Sequence

Tags: data-types

I work with linear combinations of graphs,
$$c_1 G_1 + c_2 G_2 + \dotsc,$$
and I want to represent them in my Mathematica code. I represent graphs as adjacency matrices, e.g.

```
{{0,1},{1,0}}
```

The next step is to write down linear combinations of these matrices. However, I want to implement formal linear combinations of the kind

```
lin = 5 * AdjMtx[{{0,1},{1,0}}] + 3 * AdjMtx[{{1,0},{0,1}}]
```

with an unevaluated "function" or type `AdjMtx`. The reason I don't want to write

```
5 * {{0,1},{1,0}} + 3 * {{1,0},{0,1}}
```

is that Mathematica then treats the adjacency matrices as normal matrices which admit multiplication my scalars etc.

`AdjMtx` should allow other functions to access the contents of adjacency matrices as usual. For example, a function should be able to search through a linear combination of adjacency matrices and read out their respective matrix elements.

I guess that moving through a linear combination, e.g. `lin` from above, is just done using `Part`. Then the question is how to do implement something like

```
AdjMtx[...][[3,4]]
```

Comment: Can you give one or two simple examples of a *function* that does something meaningful to `lin`?

Comment: It could be a function that replaces loops in the graph my certain numbers, just to name one example. Basically I want to access the adjacency matrices as if they were normal Mathematica lists, I want to distinguish them semantically from usual matrices.

Comment: Might be useful to work with something other than `Plus`. Less clear is whether `Times` should also be replaced or in other ways inhibited e.g. by using a head for the matrices that is not `List`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a HoldAll instead of an unevaluated function, or define your AdjMtx function as HoldAll

```
In[127]:= AdjMtx[x___] := HoldAll[x];

In[128]:= lin = 5*AdjMtx[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}] + 3*AdjMtx[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]

Out[128]= 5 HoldAll[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}] + 3 HoldAll[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]

In[129]:= lin[[1]]

Out[129]= 5 HoldAll[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}]

In[130]:= lin[[1, 2, 1, 1]]

Out[130]= {0, 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understand correclty what you are after, but I think that using `UpValues` should help you solve your problem, e.g. this definition:

```
Part[AdjMtx[data_], idcs___] ^:= Part[data, idcs]
```

will make it possible to access the matrix elements just as desired:

```
a = AdjMtx[{{1,0},{0,1}}];
a[[1,1]]
```